# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function, but it works from console

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I am starting a Laravel application and I want to use DataTables.js for displaying data from the database in it.

This is order in which I include the scripts:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My app.js file is only:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
          var table = $('#domains_table').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
            "order": [],
            "columnDefs": [ { "targets": "no-sort", "orderable": false }
            ],
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
          });
        }, 2000);

    } );
```

I've added the timeout hoping it would give everything else time to load, but it didn't.

DataTables(), however, works from the console. What am I doing wrong?

I might have two versions of jQuery because this line:

```
 "jquery": "^3.1.0"
```

is one of the dependencies in package.json, but if I leave out this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get error: **jQuery() not defined**, while **$()** works fine.

Comment: sounds like you are loading multiple versions of jQuery. Only load one and make sure all dependent plugins and code load after the library

Comment: @charlietfl But how will I then deal with jQuery() not defined error?

Comment: sounds like you are trying to use jQuery before it has loaded

Comment: It gives me the same error in console then, but $() works fine.

Comment: could you check if any of your dependencies are using `jQuery` instead of `$()`

Comment: @PaladiN https://datatables.net/ this is, that's what was causing the error in the first place.